# apex:enhancedlist width parameter has no effect?

Tags: visualforce, list-view

I'm using an apex:enhancedlist to display a predefined list view. I'm trying to limit the width of the by using the width parameter but it doesn't change the view.  Any ideas what I'm missing?  Code is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" >
   <apex:enhancedList type="Case" customizable="false" height="235" width="50" listid="00B600000074y38" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `apex:enhancedlist` inside of a `div` tag and set its width with the help of CSS.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" >
   <div style="width:300px;" >
      <apex:enhancedList type="Case" customizable="false" height="235" listid="00B600000074y38" />
   </div>   
</apex:page>
```

**P.S.** Adjust the `width` as per your need.

Comment: Thanks!  I started thinking along those lines but was uncertain of the exact syntax.